# Click events are not working in Chrome, but event fires when we execute it manually from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

From hours I am trying to find the root cause for one of tricky customer issue. Help is appreciated.

None of the clicks events in client Chrome browser is firing.

But when we call the JavaScript method from console it fires!

[image]

In the attached image you can see, how I triggered the event

Tried removing "data-bind" attribute and added simple "onClick", still does not work. none of the buttons in web site working :(

Here is code

```
<div class="row butrow p0 pb20 pt10">
<div class="col-md-12 text-left ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 text-left pl0">
            <input type="button" style="display: inline;" class="resbut" value="@SchedulingSystem.Clear" id="btnClear" data-bind="click:AppointmentView.ClickClear"/>
            <input type="button" style="display: none;" class="resbut" value="@SchedulingSystem.SkipNAdd" id="btnSkipNAdd" data-bind="click:AppointmentView.ClickSkipNAdd"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">

            <input type="button" data-bind="click:AppointmentView.SelectSearchCustomer" value="@SchedulingSystem.Select" class="subbut" id="btnSelectSearchCustomer"/>
            <button id="btnSearchCustomer" type="button" data-bind="click:AppointmentView.SearchCustomer" class=" resbut"> @SchedulingSystem.Search_Customer</button>
            <input type="button" style="display: none;" class="resbut" value="@SchedulingSystem.AddNewCustomer" id="btnAddNewCustomer" data-bind="click:AppointmentView.ClickAddNewCustomer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

None of them are getting fired.

**In IE and FireFox all buttons working as expected, issue is only on chrome**

**Solution**

Laptop was touch screen based!!

1.Type below in chrome browser :

chrome://flags/#touch-events

2.In the enable touch events section ,please select "Disable" from the drop down.

3.Click on "Relaunch Now"

Comment: when posting on stackoverflow please provide the actual code.

Comment: check if customer has disabled javascript from browser.Also check if same customer is able to log from mozilla or ie

Comment: yes in mozilla all the buttons working but not in chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**

Since the user laptop was "**HP Elitebook 840**",it was touch screen enabled.

**So solution was disabling the touch screen**

1.Type below in chrome browser :

chrome://flags/#touch-events

2.In the enable touch events section ,please select "Disable" from the drop down.

3.Click on "Relaunch Now"

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old post, but since the problem described still occurs I will provide my solution to it:

I do not have a touchscreen laptop, so I was not experiencing the issue myself - yet I needed to replicate it if I was to resolve it.
So, I went into `chrome://flags/#touch-events` and set `Enable touch events` to `Enabled`.

I reloaded Chrome, opened the developer console and pressed **⌘+⇧+M** to open the Device Mode window (it seems that this last part isn't strictly necessary).

Now I was able to replicate the problem - listeners for `click` events never fire.

In researching the issue I stumbled across library - [Tocca.js](https://gianlucaguarini.github.io/Tocca.js/). Its description reads:

> Super lightweight script (1kb) to detect via Javascript events like 'tap' 'dbltap' 'swipeup' 'swipedown' 'swipeleft' 'swiperight' on any kind of device.

To see what event, if any, *does* fire, I attached all of the event handlers that Tocca.js provides to an element exhibiting the problematic behavior:

```
var $elm=$('.log-in').last()
$elm.on('tap',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('dbltap',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('longtap',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('swipeleft',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('swiperight',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('swipeup',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
$elm.on('swipedown',function(e,data){ console.log(e,data); });
```

Then I clicked the button - and - eureka - console output!

```
r.Event {type: "tap", originalEvent: TouchEvent, timeStamp: 1471550288951, jQuery310022933444763555788: true, isTrigger: 3…} Object {x: 897.4290161132812, y: 264.85699462890625, distance: undefined}
```

Tocca.js caught the event in the `tap` event listener. As it turns out the problematic behavior can be resolved by including Tocca.js in your page and adding the `tap` event to any event listener that is listening for a `click`. To be safe I added the other two Tocca.js "tap-like" events as well:

```
$('.log-in').on('click tap dbltap longtap', function(e) { console.log("HAIL SATAN!"); })
```

While I am satisfied with using Tocca.js and have no reason to dig further, it would be fairly trivial to determine the original emitted event by inserting some debug statements into Tocca.js.

So now you know, and knowing is half the battle.

Comment: That console.log 

Answer (score 1):

I will jump to an empty pool here and do a wild guess as you did not provide any piece of code, check that those links don't have `pointer-events: none;` set in the css. That will prevent any click handler from being executed.

Comment: Same website works fine for all other users!! It's not login access issue for sure.

Comment: @taxicala : Please provide more info. which link you talking about ? where I find "pointer-events: none;"

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting the element hasn't been loaded on the dom at the time you're requiring it. So your code is basically `$(undefined).on("click", fun)` or something like that. Try writing an if condition that checks if the element itself is loaded at the time you're defining the condition and see what you come up with. Maybe `console.log` the element to make sure you have it before you define the listener?

Comment: I agree with you, since it's in production it's difficult to do experiments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer applies to the original (very old) question, but in my case, mousedown and mouseup events both fired but no click.

The problem ended up being that the target element was being redrawn/recreated from the mousedown event handler.  Most of the time, chrome would still do the click, except for one very specific situation.

After preventing that redraw, click started firing reliably again.

If I ended up here hopefully that'll help someone else that does.