# How to disable touch screen of laptops using PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, touch

My clients are using "HP Elitebook 840" touch screen laptop and recently we launched a website for their service, unfortunately click events on buttons did not worked in the web site. After a long R&D we realized it was touch screen issue and mouse click events started working after disabling it.

More info here: [Click events are not working in Chrome, but event fires when we execute it manually from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107790/click-events-are-not-working-in-chrome-but-event-fires-when-we-execute-it-manua)

Since there are more than 40 users having same touch screen laptops, we would like to run a script to disable the touch feature of these laptops. I think network admin needs to run powershell script to do it, but I could not figure it out how to write single script to disable the touch screen of systems

I was reading http://www.surfaceforums.net/threads/disable-the-touch-screen-to-use-the-pen.12338/ but since I am new to PowerShell so need more detailed steps.

Comment: Can't you just send <WinKey>+Q using SendKey? I don't have a touch screen, so I can't test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following registry key to disable touch input (requires a reboot):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch]
"TouchGate"=dword:00000000
```

Or with PowerShell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch ompany -Name TouchGate -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

Comment: It would be great to have a script to enable it back. Is it by value `1`?

Answer (score 14):

Powershell nuggets to disable/enable laptop touch screen. Tested in Windows 10 on Asus UX 501. Run as administrator.

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false

Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

([Source](https://itfordummies.net/2016/09/08/disable-touch-screen-powershell/))

Comment: Wow! This just works "out of the box". No restart required, no Devcon, not even a device ID, nothing!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works on my Lenovo Yoga, takes barely a second, and no reboot required!

Comment: I have been using this in a Powershell script for many clients that come in to my tech shop. This no longer seems to work as flawlessly as it once did.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in PowerShell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch -Name TouchGate -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

Restart machine after.

Comment: It would be great to have a script to enable it back. Is it by value `1`?

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I decided the best thing for me was to save two .bat files to handle this so that I could easily launch it using Launchy. Code below - you might need to add in logic to for the ExecutionPolicy based on your configuration, but works for me as written.

Copy this into notepad and save it as a .bat - just switch out "Disable" for "Enable" and you're good to go either direction

```
@ECHO off
Powershell.exe -Command "& {Start-Process Powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-Command ""& {Get-PNPDevice | Where-Object FriendlyName -Like ''*touch screen*'' | Disable-PNPDevice -Confirm:$false} ; Get-PNPDevice | Where-Object FriendlyName -Like ''*touch screen*'' ; if ($Host.Name -eq ''ConsoleHost'') {Write-Host ''Press any key to continue...'' ; $Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer() ; $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey(''""NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp''"") > $null}""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question and saw the answers, which are good.  However, I found that I didn't want two different scripts to enable/disable the touch screen.  I wanted to have it under one to just toggle it's state, so I wrote this script:

```
# To allow script to be executed on double click
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644946/1366368

# To sign script
# https://adamtheautomator.com/how-to-sign-powershell-script/

# To automatically elevate script to admin privs, I used this code fromn https://superuser.com/a/532109/222708
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {
    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())
    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {
    if ($elevated) {
        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting
    } else {
        # Removed -noexit as it will force the powershell instance to keep running after finishing
        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))
    }
    exit
}

# If Status of touch screen is Error, then it is off.
$result = (Get-PnpDevice|Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'}|Select -ExpandProperty 'Status')
if ($result -eq 'Error') {
  Write-Host "Enabling touch screen"
  Get-PnpDevice|Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'}|Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
} else {
  Write-Host "Disabling touch screen"
  Get-PnpDevice|Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'}|Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
}
```